# Responsive design and same height td

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a grid of 7 rectangle. Here is my code

```
<div id="insidec">
<table id="insidetabel">    
<col width="32%" />
            <col width="32%" />
            <col width="32%" />                                
 <tr>
 <td><div> 1 </div></td>
 <td><div> 2 </div></td>
 <td><div> 3 </div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><div> 4 </div></td>
 <td><div> 5 </div></td>
 <td><div> 6 </div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><div> </div></td>
 <td><div> 7 </div></td>
 <td><div> </div></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Here is css code-

```
#insidec{ 
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.01);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(83, 39, 134, 1);
text-align:center;
}
#insidetabel{
height:80%;
width:100%;
border-spacing:10px;
}

 #insidetabel td{
border-radius:10px;
height:32%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:120px)  { body{font-size:8px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:180px)  { body{font-size:10px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:240px)  { body{font-size:12px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:320px)  { body{font-size:15px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:360px)  { body{font-size:15px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:600px)  { body{font-size:15px} }
@media only screen and (min-width:800px)  { body{font-size:15px} }
```

And this is the result:[image]

Now i have two questions

1. how to make all td same height. its get changed when text inside is bigger.
2. i want it to be responsive - when used in mobile - shape changes and it becomes grid with two columns.

i think i have used all css properties to make height same, but it gets changes according to inside text(No overflow-hidden or scroll).
as i have text inside td so when one td gets stretched  all td gets padding according to the biggest one.

please suggest javascript/jquery method.

Comment: 1 - Use overflow:hidden and height:x for the height, 2 - Use % instead of pixels.

Comment: @dwhite.me i dont want inside text to get cut. 2nd it cant have fixed height cause its inside text is dynamic.

Comment: Perhaps **not** using a table might be more appropriate sinc ethis isn't (apparently) tabular data

Comment: In which case, what have you tried? We are not here to code for you.

Comment: @pleasedontbelong i have tried css but not javascript. I have used height:100%. and some other things from stackoverflow.

Comment: @riskPlayGround then just post your CSS n_n and a jsfiddle too would be nice.. makes it easier to help you

Comment: @pleasedontbelong i have posted code. sorry i dont use jsfiddle, i'm, new to this.

Comment: @dwhite.me I HAVE POSTED MY CODE. NOW HELP.

Answer (score 1):

- For the responsive problem:

You are using a table, so you won't be able to transform this into 2 columns for mobile. What you need is a grid layout (cf. bootstrap grid layouts or Foundation grids) or you could just float the elements to the left with a 33% width and use media queries to set to 50% when the screen width becomes too small, or even 100% when it gets too small

- For the height problem:

I guess that the text is dynamic so you'd probablly need a JS solution. Something like: (using jQuery)

```
var max_height = 0;
// get the max height
$("span").each(function(i, item){
    if ($(item).height() > max_height){
        max_height = $(item).height();   
    }
});
$("span").height(max_height);
```

- Here's a basic example I did using Bootstrap for the grid. It's somehow responsive, I might give you an idea how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/czES7/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#insidec{ 
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.01);
box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(83, 39, 134, 1);
text-align:center;
}
#insidetabel{
height:80%;
width:100%;
border-spacing:10px;
    min-width:220px
}

 #insidetabel td{
border-radius:10px;
height:32%;
    min-width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5aUwZ/

Comment: Its a good solution for my 2nd problem ? but what about same height and width ? how to get same height and width for all td.

Comment: Nope, width is not same, size changing according to text inside.

Comment: Do you change font-size ?

Comment: i'm using media query for fonts see changes in above code